# Simple input function Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I want to write a simple function that reads a string from console and parses it to a custom data type.

My attempt:

```
data Custom = A | B Int | C String deriving Read

getFormula::IO Custom
getFormula = do 
    putStrLn("Introduce una formula: ")
    toParse <- getLine
    return read toParse::Custom
```

But this does not work and I do not know how to interpret the resulting compiling error. How do I fix this? What am I misunderstanding about how IO functions work?

---

EDIT: This is the error I get when I try to load the file into GCHI

```
test.hs:7:5:
Couldn't match type ‘String -> a0’ with ‘Custom’
Expected type: String -> Custom
  Actual type: String -> String -> a0
The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments,
but its type ‘(String -> a0) -> String -> String -> a0’
has only three
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return read toParse :: Custom
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn ("Introduce una formula: ");
       toParse <- getLine;
         return read toParse :: Custom }

test.hs:7:5:
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO Custom’ with actual type ‘Custom’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return read toParse :: Custom
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn ("Introduce una formula: ");
       toParse <- getLine;
         return read toParse :: Custom }
In an equation for ‘getFormula’:
    getFormula
      = do { putStrLn ("Introduce una formula: ");
             toParse <- getLine;
               return read toParse :: Custom }
```

Comment: You could use `readLn` directly instead `getLine` and `read`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two type errors. The second one is easier to understand:

```
getFormula::IO Custom
```

`getFormula` is declared to have type `IO Custom`.

```
    return read toParse::Custom
```

... but here you claim the last expression has type `Custom`. `IO Custom` is not the same as `Custom`, so the compiler complains.

---

By the way, your spacing is a bit weird. Why do you have `::` jammed right against identifiers on the left and right?

```
    return read toParse :: Custom
```

looks less crowded and also less misleading: The `:: Custom` part applies to the whole expression on the left, not just a single variable.

---

The first error is a bit confused, but it contains a vital hint: `The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments`.

`return` only takes one argument:

```
return read toParse
```

should be

```
return (read toParse)
```

In order to also fix the type annotation, you can use one of the following:

- A bit clunky:

  ```
  return (read toParse) :: IO Custom
  ```
- Slightly neater (no need to specify `IO`):

  ```
  return (read toParse :: Custom)
  ```
- Easiest solution:

  ```
  return (read toParse)
  ```

  You don't need to explicitly specify a type here at all. The compiler already knows you're looking for a `Custom` because of the `getFormula :: IO Custom` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` function has one argument, but you're giving it two - the first one is `read`, the second one is `toParse`.

Use parentheses to specify the application order:

```
return (read toParse :: Custom)
```